# Network related sample app in java

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am testing one new build of jdk , against the network related aspects to check the performance of this build , so I needed any java sample application which does some I/O related stuff or like network related stuff for eg: video streaming which will be hosted on **tomcat server.**

I am absolutely novice in java programming, so any links to the sample application would be very much helpful.

Comment: Do you need any file transfer program?

Comment: No other than file transfer , anything related to I/O , network related stuff samples

Comment: Posting such long programs as source in answer will not be a good idea, here are some simple networking programs http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/